# Why am I not printing out the vector when I use the for loop and cout command

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, cout

I cannot seem to find the reason why the contents of my vector components are not supplied using the for loop and cout. Background to the code is that I want to know what happens when you resize a vector that already exists (if made smaller, which components fall away, if larger, which components are added,...)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<double> a;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
a[i] = 5;
a.resize(15)
for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
cout << a[i] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behavior because the declared vector is empty and you may not use the subscript operator for an empty vector.

```
vector<double> a;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
a[i] = 5;
```

Moreover the indices of vectors start from 0.

You could either write

```
vector<double> a( 10 );
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
a[i] = 5;
```

or

```
vector<double> a;
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
a.push_back( 5 );
```

Or to make the last code snippet more efficien you could write

```
vector<double> a;
a.reserve( 10 );
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
a.push_back( 5 );
```

Again to output the full content of the vector you should start indices from 0. Or you could use the range based for loop like

```
for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << '\';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an out-of-bounds access in your code. You need to resize your vector **before** filling it. Alternatively you can use `push_back` to insert elements.
In either case, it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You did not change the size of the vector. To insert into a vector you can use the [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) methods. If you change the insertig code to

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
  a.push_back(i);
```

or alternatively use the `resize` method before you assign

```
a.resize(10);
for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
   a[i] = i;
```

then the print loop should work fine.